# TH colspan with an odd number of columns

Tags: html, html-table

I usea HTML table with five columns and two rows.
I want to connect the columns in the last row to two cells and the border of the connected cells should be in the middle of the table. With 6 columns there wouldn't be a problem. But with an odd number there  is. Any ideas? I also used decimal values, but it doesn't work :-(

Code:

```
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="3"></th><th colspan="3"></th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does the word "impair" mean? I mean, [I know what it means](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impair?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) but in this context ... no.

Comment: not dividable by two ;-) odd...

Comment: ah I hadn't scrolled down that far :-) :-)  But anyway, sadly I don't think you can do what you want to do - "colspan" values can only be integers.

Comment: I think that's called being `odd` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since there wouldn't be a problem with six cells, make it six cells and merge the two in the center in the first row.